# Why do events in .NET use sender as parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I add an event handler for a web control in an ASPX page - why does it pass in sender? What is the advantage to using sender versus just referencing the control by its "ID" in the event handler?

I could see if I had a separate class which handled events, and multiple controls were going to be using the event handler. But if I am certain only this control will handle this event, is it bad just to reference the control ID rather than cast sender to my object type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You appear to be looking at .NET eventing just from the ASP.NET angle. The .NET event model is widely used throughout the entire .NET Framework, not just for ASP.NET pages and controls.

This pattern is flexible to allow any (properly intended) object to be the origin of an event, allowing event listeners to "zero in" on the object that raised it for further processing. Remember that events need not only have one origin and one listener/handler.

Pages and Controls are all objects so to make it flexible enough the sender is typed Object. With some programming discipline, one should be able to define the known-types that can raise that event and cast the sender object back to the original type. If it is purely a string Control ID, one would have to find the control with the matching ID which may not be easy in a page filled with a huge hierarchy of controls.

Answer (score 11):

The advantage is that you can attach the same event handler to the events of multiple controls. Since you don't know the control that raised the event in this case, you can use the `sender` argument to refer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Controls don't need to have an ID, and events can be thrown by more than controls. Making the object the sender means that you can catch events from controls without IDs and from general objects.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to above answers, the sender could be handy when you create buttons inside a [Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp). Let's say that you iterate through out 100 orders or any other data for that matter, and you want to check a button that says "OK", you don't want to be able to press "OK" twice.

So in your method you could Use the Sender as:

```
Button b = sender as Button;
b.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that you wouldn't use the control ID to reference the instance that raised an event is that the event system spans the .NET framework and not just ASP.NET. Other types that raise events don't necessarily have a control ID (and might not even be controls at all).

Answer (score 0):

Filip, dtb

With your example we are entering into the dangerous world of eventhandling.
Typecasting the sender object to some other type actually 'injects' knowledge into the eventhandler, namely that this eventhandler is being called by buttons. This makes the eventhandler unusable by other type controls or classes.

Sharing eventhandlers sounds like a good idea, but from my own experience (and looking at other peoples code) it's more often abused than used. True, with repeaters you do not have much choice.
All that I am trying to say is be carefull of what you code into the actual eventhandler and consider creating a function if it exceeds more than three lines.

Nitpicking:

```
Button b = sender as Button; 
if(b != null)
{
  b.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Or even better:

```
Button clickedButton = sender as Button; 
if(clickedButton != null)
{
  clickedButton.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Question: why is the Enabled property being rendered as a Type ?

Comment: Checking null-value on an example like this didn't feel nessesary. Even better would be to check it with typeof, however, I was only displaying some pseudo usage.